# Amount of liquid to bring on carry-in luggage - Philippines

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, philippines, check-in

Can you clarify the rules for liquid in carry-on luggage from the Philippines? It says [here](http://125.60.203.88/miaa/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=417&Itemid=134) that

> Containers for LAGs in your carry-on baggage must be one hundred (100) milliliters/grams or less. All containers must be placed in a transparent, one-liter plastic bag. Passengers are allowed only one plastic bag each.

Is the 100 ml cumulative? Like all that I bring in the carry in should total to 100 ml or I can put as much multiple containers which have less than or equal to 100 ml in capacity as the plastic bag can contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each container can hold up to 100 ml and you can take as many containers as will fit in a 1 liter plastic bag.

I'm not sure about the Philippines' interpretation of the rule, but some countries want a closable type bag (ziplocks, etc) and you have to be able to close it with all the containers inside.